# How to specify JButton state if JTextField's document is empty

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, documentlistener

So I just started reading about `DocumentListeners` and some other Action Listeners today but I can't get my `JButton` to revert to `setEnabled(false)` state when any of the text fields are empty. Is this something to do with the caret position or is there a proper way of reverting it to original state `setEnabled(false)` when any of the text fields are empty.

Here's what I've written so far.

```
public class home extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public home() {
        JPasswordField currentPasswordJPasswordField;
        JPasswordField newPasswordJPasswordField;
        JPasswordField reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField;

        currentPasswordJPasswordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new textFieldListener(saveNewPasswordButton));
        newPasswordJPasswordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new textFieldListener(saveNewPasswordButton));
        reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new textFieldListener(saveNewPasswordButton));
    }

    public static class textFieldListener implements DocumentListener {
        JButton btn;

        public textFieldListener(JButton button) {
            btn = button;
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

When I type something on the textfield it enables the save button as expected. **But when I press backspace to clear all the text, save button won't revert to** `setEnabled(false)`.

I'd appreciate any response. I just started to learn this. I also want to know if I can put the action listeners in a separate .java file. If so, how can I apply the listeners to my main class.

Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'll take note of that. I edited my post as concise as I can. I guess this is the shortest and most concise possible. Thank you.

Comment: You might notice there is more in MCVE than the 'Minimal', more to SSCCE than 'Short'. It is the other parts that I am suggesting you post code to meet. Post code we can compile, run and *see the problem.*

Answer (score 4):

Your basic approach is correct, using a `DocumentListener`, but you don't seem to be checking the length of the `Document`'s contents at any point

This is a really simple example, but until all three fields have something in them, the button won't be enabled.

You could extend the idea by also checking to see if the first two fields match, but I'll leave that up to you

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JPasswordField currentPasswordJPasswordField;
        private JPasswordField newPasswordJPasswordField;
        private JPasswordField reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField;     

        private List<JTextComponent> requiredFields = new ArrayList<>(25);

        private JButton okay;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            currentPasswordJPasswordField = makePasswordField();
            newPasswordJPasswordField = makePasswordField();
            reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField = makePasswordField();

            add(currentPasswordJPasswordField, gbc);
            add(newPasswordJPasswordField, gbc);
            add(reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField, gbc);

            okay = new JButton("Ok");
            add(okay);

            updateState();
        }

        protected JPasswordField makePasswordField() {
            JPasswordField field = new JPasswordField(20);
            field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentHandler());
            requiredFields.add(field);
            return field;
        }

        protected void updateState() {
            boolean enabled = true;
            for (JTextComponent field : requiredFields) {
                if (field.getDocument().getLength() == 0) {
                    enabled = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            okay.setEnabled(enabled);
        }

        public class DocumentHandler implements DocumentListener {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateState();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateState();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                updateState();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a KeyListener to each of the text fields and update the button from inside the anonymous inner class.

```
currentPasswordJPasswordField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyReleased(e);
        if(currentPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 && 
                newPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 && 
                reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0) {
            btn.setEnabeld(true);
        } else {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});

newPasswordJPasswordField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyReleased(e);
        if(currentPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 && 
                newPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 && 
                reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0) {
            btn.setEnabeld(true);
        } else {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});

reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        super.keyReleased(e);
        if(currentPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 && 
                newPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0 && 
                reTypeNewPasswordJPasswordField.getText().length() > 0) {
            btn.setEnabeld(true);
        } else {
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm gonna go try that. I didn't know that there's a key listener. I'm now reading the documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/api.html as well. I'll add comment if it works. I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is the way to go.

Comment: And what happens if I paste text into the field or update the field programmatically? The `KeyListener` can't deal with those use cases